# Is that safe to send sensitive data via RabbitMQ messages?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, rabbitmq

I need to send sensitive data via [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). How messages are stored in queue, when [ssl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) is used? Is it guaranteed that noone can get access messages without certificate or i need to somehow encrypt messages before insert?

Comment: I faced the same issue. Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

SSL only guarantees enctryption in flight (in traffic), not at rest (storage).
RabbitMQ as far I recall doesn't encrypt the storaged messages.

You cloud use either encrypted storage in the infrastructure level or encrypt the messages on the application level.